# Add a second recipient link in Stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Can I create a `stripe.paymentLink` with the specified transfer data so that the second recipient receives a percentage of the main cost (product has pricing model custom chooses)?

```
stripe.PaymentLink.create(
  line_items=[{"price": "XXX", "quantity": 1}],
    transfer_data={"amount": 40, "destination": destination}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `transfer_data` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create#create_payment_link-transfer_data) is used to transfer a portion of the amount charged using the Payment Link to the Connected Account specified in the `destination` following [this approach](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#transfer-amount).

You must specify an amount either in the `transfer_data` that the Connected Account receives, or in the `application_fee_amount` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create#create_payment_link-application_fee_amount) that is what the Platform retains.  There is an `application_fee_percent` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create#create_payment_link-application_fee_percent) but that is only valid for subscriptions.

Unfortunately I don't think you can achieve your desired outcome without specifying the amount the end-customer will pay.